# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Hello I'm trying to load data from a row in a .csv file on P5JS and I keep getting the error message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined. Does anyone know why I may be getting this? I have check to make sure there is nothing wrong with my .csv file.

```
 var table;
var travel = [];
function preload() {
  table = loadTable("data/travel.csv", "csv", "header");
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  textSize(24);
  travel = table.getRow(1).arr;
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  translate(0,height/1);

  for(var i = 1; i < travel.length; i++){
    translate(25,0);
    push();
    rect(0,0,20,travel[i] * 5.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Initial guess is that your travel.csv file is not properly formatted.  What do you get if you do table.getRow(0).arr?

Comment: Have you figured this out? If so, please let us know. If not, can you provide an example `csv` file?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your script with my own csv file and it worked as expected. So, I suspect the problem is in your file. You should start by trying the same code with a different csv file (grabbed from the internet or wherever).

However, I did some searching around and have found [a couple of issues](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/486) noted with load--() P5 functions and the preload() function. If you're still having no luck with this after replacing the csv file, I would try rewriting the script [with a callback function](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#callbacks) rather than using the preload() function. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a clear answer, more of a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer